# BuildUp doesn't resolve dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to use `Dependency` attribute with using `RegisterInstance`. I've read that If I use `RegisterInstance` I must use `BuildUp` method on a instance. Unfortunately it doesn't work in my code. It doesn't resolve `Alarm` property. When I use my code without `RegisterInstance` everything is ok, but I need use `RegisterInstance`. Do I miss something?

**EDIT**

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IAlarm, Alarm>();

ICar car = new Car();
container.RegisterInstance<ICar>(car);
var carFromContainer = container.BuildUp<ICar>(container.Resolve<ICar>());
var alarm = carFromContainer.Alarm;

public interface ICar
{
    IAlarm Alarm { get; set; }
}

public class Car : ICar
{
    private IAlarm _alarm;

    [Dependency]
    public IAlarm Alarm
    {
        get { return _alarm; }
        set { _alarm = value; }
    }
}

public interface IAlarm
{
    void Launch();
}

public class Alarm : IAlarm
{
    public void Launch()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Alarm !");
    }
}
```

**Old example**

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IAlarm, Alarm>();
ICar car = new Car();
container.RegisterInstance<ICar>(car);

//container.RegisterType<ICar, Car>();

var client = new Client(container);
var alarm = client.Car.Alarm;
client.Car.Alarm.Launch();

public class Client
{
    public ICar Car { get; set; }
    public Client(UnityContainer container)
    {
        //Car = container.Resolve<ICar>();
        Car = container.BuildUp<ICar>(container.Resolve<ICar>());
    }
}


public interface ICar
{
    IAlarm Alarm { get; set; }
}

public class Car : ICar
{
    private IAlarm _alarm;

    [Dependency]
    public IAlarm Alarm
    {
        get { return _alarm; }
        set { _alarm = value; }
    }
}

public interface IAlarm
{
    void Launch();
}

public class Alarm : IAlarm
{
    public void Launch()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Alarm !");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your sample code. You new up the `Car` yourself and register it with the container. Then you tell the container to map `IAlarm` to the implementing class `Alarm`. Then you inject the container into your `Client` which is something that is strongly disencouraged. DI containers should never be referenced outside the [Composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) of your application. And then you (ab)use your container as a ServiceLocator (which is considered an [anti-pattern in modern application architecture](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx)) to resolve `ICar` and inject some value into a property.

I would recommend you re-think your design instead of looking for a solution to the technical issue you face.

---

**UPDATE**

Change your interface definition for `ICar` and put the `DependencyAttribute` there and it works.

But I cannot recommend that approach either. [DI attributes should not polute your code](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/27/WhatsSoDangerousAboutADIAttribute.aspx).

Comment: Sebastian, you'are absolutely right. I agree with you. But this is only example, as easy as possible. In my real application I follow good practice you listed. I edited my post to give clearier example.